# How to wait on task that runs async method

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, nested, async-await

I'm writing WPF app and recently started working with await/async so the GUI thread does not perform any time consuming operations.

My problem is I want to load two collections from db asynchronously using Entity framework. I know I can't call two `ToListAsync()` methods on DbContext so I wanted to use tasks.

I wrote async method *LoadData()* that should wait on completing the `LoadNotifications()` and then call `LoadCustomers()`.

But when the execution gets to `await this.context.MailingDeliveryNotifications.ToListAsync();` it creates another task and somehow it doesn't care about the `task.Wait()` in my `LoadData()` method, so it calls `LoadCustomers()` before completing the first call on DbContext.

The code:

```
    public async void LoadData()
    {
        Task task = this.LoadNotifications();
        task.Wait();
        await this.LoadCustomers();
    }

    private Task LoadNotifications()
    {
        return Task.Run(() => this.LoadNotificationsAsync());
    }

    private async void LoadNotificationsAsync()
    {
        List<MailingDeliveryNotification> res = await this.context.MailingDeliveryNotifications.ToListAsync();
        this.Notifications = new ObservableCollection<MailingDeliveryNotification>(res);
    }

    private Task LoadCustomers()
    {
        return Task.Run(() => this.LoadNotificationsAsync());
    }

    private async void LoadCustomersAsync()
    {
        List<Customer> res = await this.context.Customers.ToListAsync();
        this.Customers = new ObservableCollection<Customer>(res);
    }
```

I know I can solve this using this code

```
    public async void LoadData()
    {
        List<MailingDeliveryNotification> res = await this.context.MailingDeliveryNotifications.ToListAsync();
        this.Notifications = new ObservableCollection<MailingDeliveryNotification>(res);

        List<Customer> res2 = await this.context.Customers.ToListAsync();
        this.Customers = new ObservableCollection<Customer>(res2);
    }
```

but when I will need to add another collection to load from db, this method will grow to much. I want to keep my code Clean.

Comment: Also, `async void` methods are naughty.

Comment: *Don't* use `Task.Run` just to call an async method. It isn't needed, that method *already* returns a Task and it *already* runs in the background.

Comment: And don't use `async void` except for event handlers. You *can't* await them, period. Neither `async void LoadNotificationsAsync()` nor `async void LoadData` can be awaited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplify your code:

```
public async Task LoadDataAsync()
{
    await LoadNotificationsAsync();
    await LoadCustomersAsync();
}

private async Task LoadNotificationsAsync()
{
    var res = await context.MailingDeliveryNotifications.ToListAsync();
    Notifications = new ObservableCollection<MailingDeliveryNotification>(res);
}

private async Task LoadCustomersAsync()
{
    var res = await context.Customers.ToListAsync();
    Customers = new ObservableCollection<Customer>(res);
}
```

Or probably just:

```
public async Task LoadDataAsync()
{
    Notifications = new ObservableCollection<MailingDeliveryNotification>(
        await context.MailingDeliveryNotifications.ToListAsync());

    Customers = new ObservableCollection<Customer>(
        await context.Customers.ToListAsync());
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you. But how does it work? When LoadNotifications retuns Task, does it return Task exetuing the whole method or the Task from `context.MailDeliveryNotifications.ToListAsync()` call?